# Why wont the colour of my blocks output

Tags: java, methods

I font know why my Output is not giving out any colors. I have been working on this code for the entire day and I still cant figure out whats wrong with it. All it outputs is `nullnullnull`. Please help me fix this.

Comment: Only value of the object is passed not a pointer to it

Comment: Strings are immutable objects. JB Nizet already suggested a solution

Comment: @unekwu immutability has nothing to do with this. The problem would be exactly the same with a StringBuilder, which is mutable.

Comment: Right. Java doesn't pass method arguments by reference; it passes them by value.

Comment: @user3128103 if we write the code for you, you'll pass your test, but you won't have learnt anything. Take some time to digest, read and understand. It's your homework, not ours.

Comment: @user3128103: the situation is more desperate than I thought. You can't read. I told you that you could return an object containing the three colors. unekwu told you that you could return an array. And you're asking us what you should return.

Comment: Don't give up. That's how you learn. It gets easier over time. Everyone was once a learner

Comment: I edited my code and made it different but it still wont work

Answer (score 2):

Because arguments are passed by value in Java. When passing `colour` to your method, a copy of the reference is made. The method assigns a new value to this copy, and this copy is then discarded when the method ends. The original reference in `main()` is thus left untouched.

Before the call:

```
colour --> null   //main
```

During the call

```
colour --> null   // main
            ^
copy -------|     // randomWholeNumber
```

After the assignment in the method:

```
colour --> null   // main

copy --> "B"      // randomWholeNumber
```

After the call:

```
colour --> null   // main
```

You need to return an object containing the three colours from your method, and assign the returned values to the variables in main().

Comment: Also can use globals with no parameters for func call.

Comment: So in the method I return colour="B"

Comment: Read a book or a tutorial to understand what classes and objects are, how to define your own, and return an object from a method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: It prints null because the method returns null. And it returns null because you can't expect a random number to always be equal to 1. Initialize the string to something else than null in color(), and it will print either that value, or "B".

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right  But this below line give random number that is only problem Because this line below give random number .it give different output different times  when you run this code .
I sure it is not give only null value for check you try to run different times and debug it you get this random value .

```
  int randnum=(int)(Math.random()*3)+1;
```

Comment: still goes nullnullnull

Comment: So what do i do instead of putting null

Comment: Regarding your recent edits: Please **do not** use `code formatting` for things that are not code! Your edits should not have been approved.

Comment: Actually @JonathonReinhart the question is edited by user before this question contains  int randnum=(int)(Math.random()*3)+1; line of code  this code just answer 
unekwu that code .

Comment: @user3075488 My comment had nothing to do with this question or answer. I simply did this as a means to notify you, about the edits you were recently suggesting on other questions.

Comment: Ok I edit your answer before 1 hour @JonathonReinhart you reject it

Comment: I'll leave the same message as well. Please stop putting everything in code blocks and make your edits substantial. Many of your edits are unnecessary and even set back the post.

Answer (score 0):

You could return an array and assign that to the colors in main:

```
static String[] randomWholeNumber(){
    String colors[] = new String[3];
    int randnum=(int)(Math.random()*3);
    if(randnum==0){
    colors[0]="B";
    }
    else if(randnum==1){
    colors[0]="G";
    }
    else if(randnum==2){ 
    colors[0]="R";

    int randnum2=(int)(Math.random()*3);
    if(randnum2==0){
    colors[1]="B";
    }
    else if(randnum2==1){
    colors[1]="G";
    }
    else if(randnum2==2){ 
    colors[1]="R";

    int randnum3=(int)(Math.random()*3);
    if(randnum3==0){
    colors[2]="B";
    }
    else if(randnum3==1){
    colors[2]="G";
    }
    else if(randnum3==2){ 
    colors[2]="R";
   }
   return colors;
}


//in main
String colors[] = randomWholeNumber();
colour = colors[0];
colour2 = colors[1];
colour3 = colors[2];
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but I cant use arrays

Comment: You shouldn't call the method three times. Call it once, store the result in a variable, and then get the elements of the returned array.